# Error 216 when run C++ in Jgrasp

Tags: c++, null, jgrasp

I saved the file and linked it successfully, but when I run it, the run I/O shows:

```
****----**jGRASP wedge2 error: could not run** 

("C:\Users\\***\Documents\\***\code\superbowl.exe" ).

 **----   error # 216 "(null)".**

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.****
```

How can I fix it?? I can run other programs saved in the same folder.
And I think it's nothing wrong with my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int TOUCHDOWN=6;
    const unsigned int FIELD_GOAL=3;
    const unsigned int POINT_AFTER_TOUCHDOWN=1;
    const unsigned int SAFETY=2;
    std::cout << TOUCHDOWN + FIELD_GOAL + POINT_AFTER_TOUCHDOWN + SAFETY << "\n";
    std::cout << "Carolina Panthers win" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [No problems here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a87b565d320a825e)

Answer (score 0):

216 is machine type mismatch.

Can you run the executable by double clicking it (from outside jGRASP)?